# Customize scrollbar in firefox and IE

Tags: css, scrollbar

I can customize the scrollbar in **chrome** using css like this

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 7px;
}
```

However, this does not work in Firefox (version 38) and IE (version 11)

I tried the following code but to no avail.

```
scrollbar[orient="vertical"], 
scrollbar[orient="vertical"] thumb, 
scrollbar[orient="vertical"] scrollbarbutton 
{ 
      min-width: 7px !important; 
      max-width:7px !important; 
      -moz-appearance: none !important; 

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure there's no support in Firefox and there isn't going to be any time soon.

Your best bet would be a [JQuery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/) that works across all browsers.

[Malihu Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)
[Perfect Scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/)
[Custom Scrollbar](https://plugins.jquery.com/custom-scrollbar/)